# Merging file names into one text file

Tags: unix, merge

I have 8 files that need to be merged into one text file, with each of the file names being on a separate line.

The output should be as follows:

```
file.txt:

output1/transcripts.gtf
output2/transcripts.gtf
output3/transcripts.gtf
```

and so on...

I have read several other suggestions and I know it should be an easy fix.  I have tried `dir` and `awk` but have only gotten results that has all files in one line.  I am using unix.

Comment: By "merge", do you mean concatenate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
 ls -1 output*/*.gtf > file.txt
```

or if the nesting of you sub directories is deeper and you want all files with names ending in ".gtf":

```
 find . -type f -name "*.gtf" -print | cut -b 3- > file.txt
```